# HTTP Services REST - how to have more than one PUT method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scala, rest

I am messing around with my routes file and I wish to be able to call a different method (delete instead of update).

Snippets:

```
# User management API
GET     /users                      @controllers.Users.findUsers
POST    /user                       @controllers.Users.createUser
PUT     /user/:firstName/:lastName  @controllers.Users.updateUser ( firstName: String, lastName: String )
PUT     /user/:firstName/:lastName  @controllers.Users.deleteUser ( firstName: String, lastName: String )
```

And:

```
    updateUser: (firstName, lastName, user) ->
      @$log.debug "updateUser  #{angular.toJson(user,true) }"
      deferred  = @$q.defer()

      @$http.put("/user/#{firstName}/#{lastName}",user)
        .success((data, status,headers) =>
            @$log.info("Successfully updated user - status #{status}")
            deferred.resolve(data)
        )

        .error((data,status,header) =>
            @$log.info("Faileed to update user - status #{status}")
            deferred.reject(data)
        )
        deferred.promise


    deleteUser: (firstName,lastName,user) ->
      @$log.debug "deleteUser  #{angular.toJson(user,true) }"
      deferred  = @$q.defer()

      @$http.put("/user/#{firstName}/#{lastName}",user)
        .success((data, status,headers) =>
            @$log.info("Successfully deleted user - status #{status}")
            deferred.resolve(data)
        )

      .error((data,status,header) =>
          @$log.info("Faileed to delete user - status #{status}")
          deferred.reject(data)
      )
      deferred.promise

servicesModule.service('UserService',['$log','$http','$q',UserService])
```

Does anyone know how to distinguish the two PUT routes? Or rather call a specific PUT route?

Comment: Why not use "DELETE" as the http method instead of put?

Answer (score 4):

You use **put** in delete action, instead you can use *DELETE* http request type. So it will be like

```
GET users
POST user
PUT user/:firstName/:lastName
DELETE  user/:firstName/:lastName
```

And to distinguish two similar actions, the easiest way is to change route simply, that way will be like

```
PUT user/:firstName/:lastName
PUT user/update/:firstName/:lastName
```